# What is an example of a contact force that is not a normal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, terminology, collision

I have a question about contact force and normal force.

whenever two bodies are in contact and one body tries to push another body there will be a normal force acting between them. like when we push or pull a body, when we hit a ball by a bat, when we lift a body from ground, like pushing a wall at horizontally or at an angle etc... these all are contact forces does that mean that all contact forces are normal force?

Comment: Just to be clear, "normal" is a _direction,_ not a mechanism or an explanation or anything else. When we say "normal force," we are talking about a force vector (or, a component of a force vector) that is [_normal to_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) some surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

When trying to hit a ball with a bat, you must be holding the bat firmly. The force that is helping you grip the bat is a contact force, called friction. In fact, friction is involved in many ways in each of the examples you listed.

Another contact force would be tension. The force $-kx$ exerted by springs is also a contact force. Air resistance and viscous force (both are specific types of friction) also count as contact forces.

Comment: ok but by definition of of normal force is every body in contact exert normal force an in all of these example there is contact between two bodies then there should be a normal force?

Comment: @HarshitRaj In real life situations, normal would almost always be involved ig. But what you are inferring from it is wrong. Particles of a taught rope are in contact but aren't exerting normal on each other.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing a point.

Often force diagrams show two contact forces on one object due to another object, eg a normal force, and a frictional force at right angle to it.

That is for convenience when it comes to analysis of the situation in that the normal force and the frictional force are actually the two components of the force on one object due to the other object.